# Rails - root_path returning only the current URL in production

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, nginx

Both `root_path` and `root_url` are now returning only the current URL as opposed to my home page, so the link will only refresh the page. This is only happening in production. What may be causing this issue? Thank you.

Link:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i>'.html_safe, root_path %>
```

Route:

```
root 'posts#index'
```

Comment: Does it happen locally if you run the server in production environment?

Comment: Here's what I get, along an error page, if I try to run the server locally in production: `X-Accel-Mapping header missing`

Comment: How does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: It's just returning my 500.html page currently: https://pastebin.com/4cTTx3FV

Comment: How does the generated HTML (of the link) look like? What URL do you see in href `<a href="....">` in production and development environment. It will give you clue.

Comment: Thanks! Here's what resolved the issue: https://github.com/ethanwilkins/simplr/commit/6d1819cebc1204785d38cf305e7a951c27bbd098